# Standardize the dev environment

Tags: linux

Suppose the following case: There are many developers in my company, and always a machine needs to be set up (format, install, upgrade), we have to do the same steps. What is the best way to automatize it?

I would like to install/upgrade all the necessary packages in 'apt install' style, that is, type in a fresh OS: apt install java-env and all the necessary packages from a java developer should be installed: jdk, ide, etc. And when I type: apt upgrade, all the packages, including the third-part, should be upgraded.

Could I create private deb packages declaring just the dependencies? Or would be best to just create a shell script? Remember that I'd like to install and upgrade the third-part packages, make some configurations, and perhaps I provide some private scripts.

What is the best way to do so? Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It might be more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: actually, it's not about 'software', it's about infrastructure

Comment: Infrastructure to support development teams is either a software engineering or a system administration issue, but it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers could be an option. Or just use regular VMs.

Comment: It's not about de deployment environment (where I believe docker is good), it's about the development environment, e.g. tools and IDEs. I could create an OS Image and install in each dev machine, but I can't automatize the upgrade of machines after installed.

Comment: that's ok, thank you